# Django Updateview not saving when in html but saves in admin

Tags: django

I have a big form, some fields, depends on other fields value to compute.
Since so, i used jquery blur to submit the form each time user done editing a field and redirect it to updateview again with new values.

I have this day_absent and amount absent to test this.
If i just put form.day_absent in the form and put object.amt_absent, it doesnt save the form. But if i put form.amt_absent, it saves the form.

Why is that? I do not wish to put amt_absent as editable, it should just be the day_absent.

```
class PayrollTransactionUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
model = t_pay
template_name = 'payroll/transaction/update.html'

fields = [
    'day_absent',
    'amt_absent',
]

      <div id='input-item' class="col-1">
        {{ form.day_absent }}
        {{ form.day_absent.errors}}

      </div>
      <div id='item' class="col-2">
        {{ object.amt_absent }}
      </div>
```

Comment: make `amt_absent` as readonly if you dont want it to be editable or make it `required = False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of points:

1. When you use `{{object.amt_absent}}`, you are not rendering the form for the field `amt_absent`, rather just the value saved in the DB.
2. You added `amt_absent` as a field to be included in the UpdateView, so, until and unless this field is not required, the form will keep throwing error for this field. That is why your form works when you include both the fields. You can check all errors by using `{{form.errors}}` or field specified errors by using `{{form.amt_absent.errors}}` in your template.

Comment: Thanks Aman, its working now. Is it okay that im doing this? I fear that it may cause some problem in my database would it not? since user may trigger multiple save to database. to give u an idea (https://imgur.com/a/SsWeZng) this is what the form looks like

Comment: No, it is just a form. You can control which field to show, how to process it etc. when you use `{{object.amt_absent}}`, you are just making a read from the DB. Here, you are simple handling how the form is being rendered, so it is all good. For handling form processing from views, refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)